# Redirect users when entering a link

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know there are other posts asking around the same question, but I cannot seem to make them work.

When a user types

```
http://mywebsite.com/msdns/[letters, numbers, and symbols here]
```

I need it to go to my page:

```
http://mywebsite.com/msdns/index.php?q=[letters, numbers, and symbols here]
```

What I have so far is this in my .htaccess file (located in the same folder as index.php):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ /index.php?q=$1
```

This however does not work. Any solutions?

Thank you in advance, pat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place this rule in your `/msdns/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /msdns/

RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).+)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I just did, when you answered I had to wait like 15 minutes ;)